# Excel Visual basic help needed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a scenario here where in I have a three tab called 
Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 and Column H of each sheet contains date.

What i want a VBA program where in user defines
the start date and end date using input box and the 
program has to loop in column H to find if the 
date on cells falls in between the date range specified
by the user in the input box. If the program is able
to find a date which is between the range specified by the 
user then copy that row and paste in a new tab called "FINAL"
in the same way it has to go to sheet 2 and perform the same action
and copy the row and paste in "FINAL" Tab.

So if you see two looping is required onc in the column H and 
then in Sheets

I have written some thing like this but having a hard time to get this 
done, any help on this respect will greatly be appreciated.

```
Sub CopyData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim inputboxa As Date
    Dim inputboxb As Date
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range

    inputboxa = startdate
    inputboxb = enddate

    startdate = InputBox("Enter Start Date" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "dd/mm/yyyy Format", "Lease", "01/02/2014", 500, 700)
    enddate = InputBox("Enter enddate Date" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "dd/mm/yyyy Format", "Lease", "28/02/2014", 500, 700)

    For Each ws In Worksheets

        If ws.Visible = True And ws.Name <> "303010 V094" Then
            Sheets(ws.Name).Select

            For Each cell In Range("H1:H1000").Cells
                ''Range("h1:h1000").Select
                ''Do Until Range("h1:h1000").Value = vbNullString
                If Range(cell).Value >= startdate And Range("h1").Value <= enddate Then
                    Range(cell).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("test").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
                End If
            Next cell

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            ''End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you will want to use **datediff** to compare date value:

```
Sub CopyData()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim inputboxa As Date
Dim inputboxb As Date
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range


inputboxa = startdate
inputboxb = enddate


startdate = InputBox("Enter Start Date" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "dd/mm/yyyy Format", "Lease", "01/02/2014", 500, 700)
enddate = InputBox("Enter enddate Date" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "dd/mm/yyyy Format", "Lease", "28/02/2014", 500, 700)


For Each ws In Worksheets


If ws.Visible = True And ws.Name <> "303010 V094" Then
Sheets(ws.Name).Select

For Each cell In Range("H1:H1000").Cells

''Range("h1:h1000").Select
''Do Until Range("h1:h1000").Value = vbNullString

If DateDiff("d", cell.Value, startdate) <= 0 And DateDiff("d", cell.Value, enddate) > 0 Then
cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("test").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
End If
Next cell


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
''End If
End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

User **Cell** instead of **Range(Cell)**.  Also make sure your date format is actually "dd/mm/yyyy" or comparing will fails by reading incorrect value, and that sheets("test")'s column A isn't empty (or you will be rewriting to the same cell over and over)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code.

1. `Range(cell)` is redundant; just use `cell`
2. You're not declaring startdate/enddate.  And you're declaring inputboxa/inputboxb but not using them.
3. You are reading startdate/enddate as a string, but then comparing it to the values in Column H which are most like in Date format.  You need to convert startdate/enddate to a Date value before comparing.
4. The `.Cells` in `Range("H1:H1000").Cells` is not necessary.
5. Not sure why you're shutting off `ScreenUpdating` then turning it back on after every sheet is processed.  You probably want to do it once at the end.

Try the following code.  Note that this assumes that your local date format is dd/mm/yyyy.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range

    startDate = DateValue(InputBox("Enter Start Date" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "dd/mm/yyyy Format", "Lease", "01/02/2014", 500, 700))
    endDate = DateValue(InputBox("Enter enddate Date" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "dd/mm/yyyy Format", "Lease", "28/02/2014", 500, 700))

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Visible = True And ws.Name <> "303010 V094" And ws.Name <> "test" Then
            Sheets(ws.Name).Select

            For Each cell In Range("H1:H1000")
                If cell.Value >= startDate And cell.Value <= endDate Then
                    cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("test").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
                End If
            Next cell

        End If
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Worst offender is that sheet _test_ has to be hidden or otherwise there will be chaos. So better explicitly do not iterate over your target sheet.

Comment: @amadeus Very true; I had assumed that was the case but it would be safer to exclude it specifically.  I will update my answer to include a check for that.